# AJAX example not working locally

Tags: ajax

I copied the example from http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first and saved it locally to test.html on my computer. Yes I did make an ajax_info.txt file too, but when I click the button nothing happens, and on w3schools works fine. Any ideas?

Here is the copied code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ajax doesn't work locally. You need to have a webserver to post to.

Comment: I thaught the same thing but ... how about if he DOES have a webserver in his local machine for tests purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your machine \ environment setup to serve that text file over HTTP i.e. when you press the button the client - i.e. your browser will do a GET HTTP to a server i.e. you localmachine running a web server (iis/apache etc) or remote box if configured

Answer (score 0):

Does your ajax_info.txt file have the contents of:

< p>AJAX is not a new programming language.< /p> 
< p>AJAX is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages.< /p>

There is no space in < p> and < /p>. I put it in just for formatting purpuses.
Side note: when you learn the fundamentals of ajax, you will find it much easier to work with jQuery's versions of it. Much simpler!!!!

Comment: yes, the file did have that - Alan's post made me realize my problem. And yes, I know about jQuery, just had to do this example..